# Applicability of prior art for WO2014081967A1

Tags: prior-art, wo2014081967a1

In reference to the patent: [WO2014081967A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2014081967A1)

The commercial product described in the following presentation, by TEL, (see link below) appear to describe a system with many, if not all of the claims in this patent application. I have not seen any reference to this system in the prior art however, the date on the presentation (Oct, 2012) precedes the priority date of this patent. Assuming that this product was commercially available prior to the priority claim of this patent application, and to the extent that the system described by TEL consitutes prior art, I would assume that the claims presented in this patent application will not hold?

http://dds.tet.tw/tetoerl/aboutus.pdf

http://www.solardds.com/